# 1D bin packing with Time Windows

Tags: mixed-integer-programming

Hi StackOverflow Experts!

I have a 1D Bin packing satisfaction problem (i.e. number of bins are given and need not be minimized).
This problem I believe is quite straight-forward, and a MIP formulation may be found e.g. here: https://medium.com/swlh/exploring-the-bin-packing-problem-f54a93ebdbe5

However, what if the blocks to pack have Time Windows?
Example:  Assume each bin has height between 70 and 100. Some blocks have an open TimeWindow, implying that they may be positioned anywhere (in any bin).  But if a block that is 5 large have a TimeWindow equal to for instance [50,60], the start of the block must be positioned at 50 or later, and the end of the block must be position at 60 or earlier.  (I.e. the block must be positioned just below the mid point of a bin 100 tall, if position 0 is at top of the bin and position 100 at bottom of bin).

The bins have (integer) sizes of around 50-100, the blocks have sizes around 2-25, and the TimeWindows are typically 6-100 large.

So, the problem is no longer only to find the best bin for each block, but also to position each block within its allocated bin.

Should be an interesting problem!  Anyone with good MIP formulation?  :-)

Answer (score 1):

This can be modelled as a scheduling problem on parallel machines. Let's introduce some notation:

- Let `J` be the set of jobs (blocks) and `M` the set of machines (bins)
- `r_j` and `d_j` will be the beginning and end of job `j` time window (*r* for release date and *d* for deadline)
- `c_jm` is the cost of processing job `j` on machine `m`, and `p_jm` the time it takes to process `j` in `m`
- `x_jm` a binary variable that's 1 if job `j` is assigned to machine `m`, 0 otherwise
- `y_ij` another variable that's 1 if jobs `i` and `j` are assigned to the same machine, with job `i` preceding job `j`; 0 otherwise
- `s_j` and `e_j` continuous variables for `j`'s start and end time, respectively

With this, according to Sadykov and Wolsey [SW] the following is a well known MIP formulation:

[image: formula]

Where the objective function minimizes total processing cost (the objective function could be changed to another thing as OP only wants to solve for satisfiability), while the constraints represent:

1. every job is assigned to a unique machine.
2. relates the jobs' start and completion time.
3. ensures that if `y_ij = 1`, i.e., `i` is processed before `j` and by the same machine, then processing of `j` must begin after `i` ends. Here, `U` is a *sufficiently large* constant, which can be set to e.g. `U = max_j d_j - min_j r_j`.
4. and 5. are there to respect time windows.
5. logical constraint; at most one of `i` and `j` can be processed before the other one
6. guarantees that if `i` and `j` are assigned to `m`, then one must be processed before the other one.
7. if jobs `i` and `j` are assigned to different machines, then `y_ij = 0` and `y_ji = 0`.
8. and 10. restrict variable domain.

The reference above includes several inequalities to tighten the model, and a computational benchmark comparing and combining the models with Constraint Programming.

**Edit:** In OP's case, all bins are equal, therefore we could simplify the model to consider equal machines (in terms of a unique costs `c_j` and processing time `p_j` per job, independently of the machine).

---

[SW] Sadykov, R., & Wolsey, L. A. (2006). Integer programming and constraint programming in solving a multimachine assignment scheduling problem with deadlines and release dates. *INFORMS Journal on Computing, 18*(2), 209-217. [Available online on ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220669091_Integer_Programming_and_Constraint_Programming_in_Solving_a_Multimachine_Assignment_Scheduling_Problem_with_Deadlines_and_Release_Dates).